# mysqli_query() expects exactly 2 parameters 1 given

Tags: php

Alguém me ajuda com esses 2 erros?

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Flexor\config.php on line 11

---

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_error()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Flexor\config.php:11 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Flexor\logar.php(2): include() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Flexor\config.php on line 11

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //Servidor do mysql
$user = "root"; //Usuario do banco de dados
$senha = ""; //senha do banco de dados
$db = "jpec"; //banco de dados
$nome_site = "nome"; //Nome do site
$email = "email@host.com"; //E-mail do administrador
$site = "http://www.jpecinformatica.com"; //Seu site n se esuqece de bota o http://

mysqli_connect($host, $user, $senha) or die (mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o próprio erro diz, `mysqli_select_db` espera dois parâmetros, mas só recebeu 1. De acordo com a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php), o `mysqli_select_db` deveria receber um link, que é gerado pelas funções `mysqli_connect` ou `mysqli_init`, ou seja:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $senha);
mysqli_select_db($link, $db);
```

Quanto ao erro `Call to undefined function mysql_error`, novamente, segundo a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) essa função foi descontinuada, use `mysqli_error` conforme indicado [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php). Para tratar erros durante o `mysqli_connect`, utilize `mysqli_connect_error`:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $senha) or die(mysqli_connect_error());
mysqli_select_db($link, $db) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```